# Deffering rendering of Vue blocks until data loaded

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm using Vue with Vue router. A common problem is when loading a component which displays some sort of external resource which requires some asynchronous loading.

Say I have a simple Vue component which displays the title of a post loaded from an external repo:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ post.title }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      post: null
    }
  },

  route: {
    waitForData: true,
    data () {
      return postRepo.fetch(this.$route.params.id)
      .then(post => {
        return {post: post}
      })
      .catch(err => { console.warn(err) })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

My route `data` method returns a promise that when resolved returns the post object that gets inserted into the component's data.

This all works fine and the post title is displayed in the page once the post is loaded but the console throws a warning:

> [Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "post.title": TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null

The problem is that Vue is trying to render the template before the post has been set. Is there a way to prevent template rendering (which is what I thought `waitForData` is for) until the `route.data()` method is resolved?

I know I can use `v-if` but I'd like to avoid excessive DOM manipulations if possible.

Answer (score 2):

http://router.vuejs.org/en/pipeline/data.html

The recommended approach is to put the stuff that relies on loaded data inside a:

```
<div v-if="!$loadingRouteData"></div>
```

Comment: this solution is no longer valid, see: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration-vue-router.html#loadingRouteData-removed